# Extracting information from a table except header of the table using bs4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extracting information from a table using bs4 and python.
when I am using the following code to extract information from header of the table:

```
    tr_header=table.findAll("tr")[0]
    tds_in_header = [td.get_text()  for td in tr_header.findAll("td")]
    header_items= [data.encode('utf-8')  for data in tds_in_header]
    len_table_header = len (header_items)
```

It works, but for the following codes that I am trying to extract information from the first row to the end of the table:

```
    tr_all=table.findAll("tr")[1:]
    tds_all = [td.get_text()  for td in tr_all.findAll("td")]
    table_info= [data.encode('utf-8')  for data in tds_all]
```

There is the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

Can anyone help me to edit it.

This is table information:

```
    <table class="codes"><tr><td><b>Code</b>
</td><td><b>Display</b></td><td><b>Definition</b></td>
</tr><tr><td>active<a name="active"> </a></td>
<td>Active</td><td>This account is active and may be used.</td></tr>
<tr><td>inactive<a name="inactive"> </a></td>
<td>Inactive</td><td>This account is inactive
 and should not be used to track financial information.</td></tr></table>
```

This is the output for tr_all:

```
[<tr><td><b>Code</b></td><td><b>Display</b></td><td><b>Definition</b></td></tr>, <tr><td>active<a name="active"> </a></td><td>Active</td><td>This account is active and may be used.</td></tr>, <tr><td>inactive<a name="inactive"> </a></td><td>Inactive</td><td>This account is inactive and should not be used to track financial information.</td></tr>]
```

Comment: You should probably post html code You are trying to parse. Moreover, since `tr_header`  is single bs4 element You can call findAll on it. But for list of rows (and that is what You probably get from `tr_all`) You need to call findAll on each element not on whole list (using double list comprehension or better - separate for loop - for readability)

Comment: @JustMe, thank you ! Even for this code tr_all=table.findAll("tr") I still get a list, but for this one:  tr_header=table.findAll("tr")[0] I do not get a list. I am totally confused. I have another question. Is it possible to edit this code to add table information from the first row to the end of the table: table_information = [td.get_text()  for td in table.findAll("td")]. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Your first question,

```
import bs4

text = """
<table class="codes"><tr><td><b>Code</b>
</td><td><b>Display</b></td><td><b>Definition</b></td>
</tr><tr><td>active<a name="active"> </a></td>
<td>Active</td><td>This account is active and may be used.</td></tr>
<tr><td>inactive<a name="inactive"> </a></td>
<td>Inactive</td><td>This account is inactive
 and should not be used to track financial information.</td></tr></table>"""

table = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text)
tr_all = table.findAll("tr")[1:]
tds_all = []
for tr in tr_all:
    tds_all.append([td.get_text() for td in tr.findAll("td")])
    # if You prefer double list comprefension instead...
table_info = [data[i].encode('utf-8') for data in tds_all
                                      for i in range(len(tds_all))]
print(table_info)
```

yields

```
['active ', 'Active', 'inactive ', 'Inactive']
```

And regarding Your second question

> tr_header=table.findAll("tr")[0] i do not get a list

True, `[]` is indexing operation, which selects first element from list, thus You get single element. `[1:]` is slicing operator (take a look at nice [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html) if You need more information).

Actually, You get list two times, for each call of table.findAll("tr") - for header and rest of rows. Sure, this is quite redundant.
If You want to separate tokens from header and rest, I think You likely want something like this

```
tr_all = table.findAll("tr")
header = tr_all[0]
tr_rest = tr_all[1:] 
tds_rest = []
header_data = [td.get_text().encode('utf-8') for td in header]

for tr in tr_rest:
     tds_rest.append([td.get_text() for td in tr.findAll("td")])
```

and regarding third question

> Is it possible to edit this code to add table information from the first row to the end of the table?

Given Your desired output in comments below:

```
rows_all = table.findAll("tr")
header = rows_all[0]
rows = rows_all[1:]

data = []
for row in rows:
    for td in row:
        try:
            data.append(td.get_text())
        except AttributeError:
            continue
print(data)

# or more or less same as above, oneline
data = [td.get_text() for row in rows for td in row.findAll("td")]
```

yields

```
[u'active', u'Active', u'This account is active and may be used.', u'inactive', u'Inactive', u'This account is inactive and should not be used to track financial information.']
```

Comment: thank you ! my desired output is this: [u'active ', u'Active', u'This account is active and may be used.', u'inactive ', u'Inactive', u'This account is inactive and should not be used to track financial information.']

Comment: The output of your code just include ['active ', 'Active', 'inactive ', 'Inactive']

Answer (score 0):

JustMe answered this question correctly.
Another equivalent variant would be:

```
import bs4

text = """
<table class="codes"><tr><td><b>Code</b>
</td><td><b>Display</b></td><td><b>Definition</b></td>
</tr><tr><td>active<a name="active"> </a></td>
<td>Active</td><td>This account is active and may be used.</td></tr>
<tr><td>inactive<a name="inactive"> </a></td>
<td>Inactive</td><td>This account is inactive
 and should not be used to track financial information.</td></tr></table>"""

table = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text)
tr_all = table.findAll("tr")[1:]
# critical line:
tds_all = [ td.get_text() for each_tr in tr_all for td in each_tr.findAll("td")]
# and after that unchanged:
table_info= [data.encode('utf-8')  for data in tds_all]

# for control:
print(table_info)
```

This strange construction in the critical line serves as flattening of the list of list 'tds_all'. lambda z: [x for y in z for x in y] flattens the list of list z. I replaced x and y and z according to this specific situation.

Actually I came to it, because I had as an inbetween-step as the critical line:
tds_all = [[td.get_text()  for td in each_tr.findAll("td")] for each_tr in tr_all ]
which generates a list of lists for tds_all:
[[u'active ', u'Active', u'This account is active and may be used.'], [u'inactive ', u'Inactive', u'This account is inactive\n and should not be used to track financial information.']]
To flatten this, one needs this [x for y in z for x in y] composition.
But then I thought, why not apply this structure right to the critical line and flatten it thereby?

z is the list of bs4-objects (tr_all). In this 'for ... in ...'-construct, each_tr (a bs4-object) is taken from the list 'tr_all', and the each_tr object generates in the behind 'for-in'-construct a list of all 'td' matches, by the expression each_tr.findAll("td") from which every match "td" is isolated by this behind 'for ... in ...'-loop, and at the very beginning of this listexpession stands what should be then collected in the final list:
the text isolated from this object("td.get_text()"). And this resulting final list is assigned to td_all.

The result of this code is this result list:

```
['active ', 'Active', 'This account is active and may be used.', 'inactive ', 'Inactive', 'This account is inactive\n and should not be used to track financial information.']
```

The two longer elements were missing in the example is of JustMe. I think, Mary, you want to have them included, isn't it?